# is it possible to deploy symfony web site on android platform?

Tags: android, symfony

I'm a C++/Qt developper and starting web development

I discover symfony framework that looks very great for me... BUT... Life is never so simple...

I would to develop a sort of web app on android platform (smartphone, tablet...and don't want to develop native android app, too complexe...) It is for internal organisation use and would be a device local website (http://localhost)
I have installed palapa web server on my smartphone but I'm stucked to go further with symfony installation/deployment
Do I have access to system/php commands with palapa/android ?

Do I have access rights to install symfony and composer and so on in palapa reps ?

What is the way to do it ?

How to deploy symfony on palapa server ?
... So I'm stucked.. :/

Great thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try reinventing the wheel...

If you want to develop a mobile android application use Java with android studio.

If you want to develop a web application Symfony sound greats. Couple with Bootstrap offer the possibility to manage every screen size and browser like smartphone but **in a browser**.

If you want to develop a cross platform mobile application take a look here for example :

- Cordova https://cordova.apache.org/
- Titanium https://www.appcelerator.com/mobile-app-development-products/